# Can i use nikkor AF lens in nx3000?

Tags: nikon, old-lenses, samsung

I'm not a professional photographer and I have an NX3000. I found an analogic N50 that is no longer working, but is there any way i can still use the lens, an AF Nikkor 35-80 Mm F4, on my NX?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not without an adapter. 
The ¿Samsung? NX3000 uses the NX-bajonett and Nikkor lenses uses the Nikon F-bajonett, so if you want to mount the lens on your NX you will need an adapter.